# PHP open source hotel booking system

Tags: php

I know that this question as been asked somewhere else, but I did not find the answer I was looking for.

I am looking for an open source hotel booking system in PHP (both front-end and back-end). I had a look around but I have not found anything intersting.

Could you please adivise any good one?

Much appreciated. Thank you.
Fracesco

Comment: Will you be connecting to a GDS?

Comment: No. This is going to be a single website.

Answer (score 0):

There is a module for Drupal called [OpenResort](http://drupal.org/project/openresort) that's close to what you're looking for, I think.

Comment: Thank you Dave,but I am not going to use Drupal.

Comment: In that case you might be out of luck. I did a similar search a year ago and found nothing - ended up writing a bespoke booking engine.

Comment: It looks like I am going to do the same thing. Thank you Dave.